# "Denormalized data" when trying to export from Excel to XML

Tags: xml, excel

I've been having this particular problem for quite a while now. 
Essentially, I've got an Excel list of various products that need to be exported to an XML file. The instant I map the first XML element to the first row of data - A recurring customer number in this case - I get the "denormalized data" error. Now, as far as I understand, this means Excel is unhappy with the customer number being the same for every row:

[image: Excel]

(The LKZ row is formatted as plain text but changing the formatting to  numbers doesn't seem to help either.)

Copying the data to a new Excel sheet does work but ONLY for a single row.
Exporting it will consequently only export a single row of data.

I'm not certain the XML scheme that we got provided with is entirely correct: 
[image: Example file]

I tried setting the maxOccurs to unbounded but I either didn't do it right or I'm on the wrong track in that regard. (If somebody would be nice enough to give an example of how maxOccurs SHOULD look it'd be appreciated.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like nobody really has an answer. Can't blame you guys.

I ended up brute forcing the issue by writing a macro that creates an entirely new XML file. If anyone cares, here is the code. Keep in mind I don't usually work with VBA so it's probably not super elegant.

```
Sub Text()

Dim arrHeader() As String, Max As Integer, Col As Integer, arrContent() As String, Row As Integer
Dim filesys, testfile, XTab As String

STab = "    "
Max = 1

Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set testfile = filesys.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\edvpr\Desktop\test.xml", True)

testfile.WriteLine "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>"
testfile.WriteLine "<ottopartner xmlns=""http://www.ottogroupb2b.com/ottopartner"">"

Do
    Max = Max + 1
Loop Until Cells(1, Max) = ""
Col = 1
ReDim arrHeader(1 To Max - 1) As String
Do
    arrHeader(Col) = Cells(1, Col)
    Col = Col + 1
Loop Until Col = Max

Row = 2
ReDim arrContent(1 To Max - 1) As String
Do
    Col = 1
    If Row = 2 Then
    Do
        arrContent(Col) = Cells(Row, Col)

        If arrContent(Col) <> "" And arrHeader(Col) = "LKZ" Then
            testfile.WriteLine "<" + Trim(arrHeader(Col)) + ">" + Trim(arrContent(Col)) + "</" + Trim(arrHeader(Col)) + ">"
            testfile.WriteLine "<Styles>"
        End If
    Col = Col + 1
    Loop Until Col = Max
    End If

    Col = 1

    Do
        arrContent(Col) = Cells(Row, Col)
        If Trim(arrContent(Col)) <> "" And Trim(arrHeader(Col)) <> "LKZ" Then
            If Trim(arrHeader(Col)) = "OrderQuantityDefault" Then
                XTab = STab + STab
                testfile.WriteLine XTab + "<Item>"
            End If

            If Trim(arrHeader(Col)) = "InvoicingStartDate" Then
                XTab = STab + STab + STab
                testfile.WriteLine XTab + "<SKU>"
            End If

            If Trim(arrHeader(Col)) = "StyleNo" Then
                If Row > 2 Then
                    testfile.WriteLine XTab + "</SKU>"
                    XTab = STab + STab
                    testfile.WriteLine XTab + "</Item>"
                    XTab = STab
                    testfile.WriteLine XTab + "</Style>"
                End If

                XTab = STab
                testfile.WriteLine XTab + "<Style>"
            End If

            testfile.WriteLine XTab + STab + "<" + Trim(arrHeader(Col)) + ">" + Trim(arrContent(Col)) + "</" + Trim(arrHeader(Col)) + ">"
        End If
        Col = Col + 1
    Loop Until Col = Max

    Row = Row + 1

Loop Until Cells(Row, 1) = ""
testfile.WriteLine "</SKU>"
testfile.WriteLine "</Item>"
testfile.WriteLine "</Style>"
testfile.WriteLine "</Styles>"
testfile.WriteLine "</ottopartner>"

testfile.Close

End Sub
```

The macro reads the first line left to right to create the tags, then fills them with the rest of the data top to bottom. It also indents the XML because OCD.